# JQmath not displaing division in jetpack compose webview

Tags: webview, android-jetpack-compose

When i try to display the division symbol in webview (jetpack compose) using jqmath i get below. What is wrong? Everything works ok when using same code in browser

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8nOcM.png**strong text**